# How to invert function keys on Dell N5010?

Tags: laptop, dell-inspiron, function-keys

There are similar posts, but those are for different laptop. I am using Dell Inspiron N5010. I couldn't find how to invert fn keys either from BIOS or from Windows Mobility Center.

How to invert function keys on Dell N5010?

Answer (score 5):

http://www.techsupportforum.com/forums/f108/dell-n5010-function-keys-496208.html

> I found the solution for reversing the Fn keys on Dell N5010 from the User manual.
>   It can be done either from the Bios or from the Windows Mobility Center program - I used the latter: Press Windows key + "X". When it opens the Win Mob Center, in the Function key row, choose 'Function key' as the Fn Key behaviour. Voila - it's back to business.

are you sure you did not miss it?

See page 36 of this document

[N5010 Technology Guide](http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/systems/xlob/dtg/en/en_dtg.zip)

.

All your Docs for that [Model](http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/systems/insN5010/en/index.htm)

Comment: Well in don't see function key row in Windows Mobility Center http://img101.imageshack.us/i/winmobcenter.png

Comment: I guess you will have to contact Dell support, sorry I cannot help further.

Comment: @templar for the fact that the fuction key does not appear please do install the dell quickset application( found on your driver cd/can also be found in app store of dell).Once installed you will be able to use the method explained above to swith on and off the fn key that is windows+x then from the function key tile you will be able to put it on or off.

Answer (score 1):

I did it using BIOS option, enter the BIOS, in it there is one slot for the function key. Reverse it to multimedia key, save and exit.

Comment: Well I have already said that it's not there..