# How to invert the Fn key

Tags: laptop, function-keys, fn-key

I have this problem on my laptop:
If my Fn key is pressed, the normal (PC-like) <kbd>F1</kbd> - <kbd>F12</kbd> keys will be triggered; when it isn't, then the *special* keys will be triggered (e.g. brightness control, sound volume).

Is there any way I can invert this, so that when I press the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key the *special* keys will be triggered and when I don't the <kbd>F1</kbd> - <kbd>F12</kbd>  keys will?

Comment: Check your BIOS/UEFI settings. There may also be a laptop manufacturer's tool that will be able to change that behavior.

Comment: What's your laptop exact model?

Comment: How about telling us your OS?

Comment: Related: [How to invert function keys on Dell N5010?](http://superuser.com/q/250684/194694)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

That's probably due to an extra option in the BIOS made by the manufacturer. When booting press F2 (usually) to get into the BIOS settings and there you can revert back to function keys instead of multimedia.

Have you tried to press the numbers lock key to change the fn keys functions?

Answer (score 202):

On my Dell XPS 15, it seems to be as simple as me accidentally pressing the <kbd>Fn Lock</kbd> button behind the Escape key. If you have this problem, simply hit <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> and it should revert back to normal, without having to go into the BIOS

Comment: Also some ThinkPad laptops (in my case me E440), the Fn+Esc solved the problem. Thanx!

Comment: Excellent! I didn't even see that little lock symbol with FN inside it on the ESC key. Kinda obvious once you know what it is. :o)

Comment: Oh wow, what a lifesaver!

Comment: Even worked on my non Laptop Keyboard "Leopold FC 660M" (I pressed "FN + 1" to revert back to normal).

Comment: On my Dell Inspiron 7786 `FN+ESC` switch between Functions and Multimedia ... Thanks

Comment: This made my PC suspend.

Comment: Wow, this was rediculous.

Comment: What a ridiculously easy fix for such a frustrating problem. And no need to venture into the BIOS to sort it out. Thank you.

Answer (score 29):

On my Dell laptop I pressed Fn + Esc and the problem is solved for me. If you closely notice, there is a small lock (Fn written on it) sign on the Esc. Apparently, you can change the default behavior of Fn key using Fn + Esc.

Answer (score 8):

It depends on the manufacturer, and sometimes even on the model. Some keyboards have a physical switch hidden somewhere, some keyboards support pressing [fn+caps](https://superuser.com/questions/847172/why-is-my-windows-surface-pro-fn-key-stuck-on), others require changing [a setting in the bios](https://superuser.com/questions/250684/how-to-invert-function-keys-on-dell-n5010).

The last resort, which is far from ideal but works on all models, is the software approach using [AutoHotKey](https://superuser.com/questions/602281/microsoft-sculpt-mobile-keyboard-reverse-fn-keys).

Comment: Unfortunately, my new gaming laptop (Gigabyte Aero) completely lacks any way to invert the Fn key (no Fn lock feature in bios, etc.)  So your suggestion offers the only hope!

Answer (score 7):

Some Microsoft keyboards will recognize this keystroke as a toggle: [“Fn” + “Caps”](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/toml/2013/10/30/surface-pro-and-function-fn-key-lock/)

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem using a Lenovo Ideapad.

Solution for me was to turn off laptop, press the NOVO key, (reset and systems start, small button next to the powercord) and start up in bios mode.

In functions change the fn/fx option from "hotkey" to "legacy"

Comment: Another solution for Lenovo usb keyboard is installing a driver which I had to use, anyone interested see this accepted answer http://superuser.com/questions/752800/how-to-disable-or-reverse-fn-key-i-want-to-replace-fnf1-fnf2-fnf3-f

Comment: If you installed "Lenovo Vantage" and enabled its toolbar you can open it and toggle the "F1" symbol

Answer (score 3):

Samsung laptops have <kbd>Fn Lock</kbd> key between F12 and PrtScr / Insert.

Though the result is slightly different - it does not revert function of <kbd>Fn</kbd> key, but works as if it was always on (unlike Caps Lock).

Answer (score 3):

For HP, press the F10 key to open BIOS Setup when starting the computer, then navigate to find Action Keys Mode, and toggle the selection.

Comment: On my HP EliteBook the default setting is also that the fn button is inverse (i.e. when you press any of the function keys, like F1 for help or F5 to refresh, then instead of triggering the Funtion-keys, it changes the volume or something random), very annoying. I noticed my fn key can be 'locked' so that it would trigger the f-keys correctly. Holding my Shift+fn key locks the fn key so it is inverse. My fn key has a background light to indicate when it is locked.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with a Logitech K290 Comfort Keyboard keyboard where for some reason it appeared that Logitech had decided for me that I would be better off with the keys switched.

Once I downloaded the setup software ([SetPoint](http://support.logitech.com/en_gb/product/comfort-keyboard-k290#download)) I was able to untick "`Swap F key functions`" and it went back to normal behaviour (thankfully, as with software development the last thing you want is to keep choosing that you actually want the function key you pressed!).

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is to search for **Windows Utility Center** or **Mobility Center**. To get this option press Windows+X which gets you a a popup menu in the left corner of the screen. From there select Mobility Center or Windows Utility Center, and from there assign for your function keys.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: *"assign for your function keys"*, assign *what*? Is there an option there to invert the Fn key?

Comment: Some manufactures add a custom option here to invert the fn key.

Answer (score 1):

You need to restart (to enter in BIOS) your computer to change this.

While first black screen comes Press <kbd>F2</kbd> (this may differ in your laptop).

If a bios screen (may be unknown to you) appear then find `Function Key Behavior` select `Multimedia Key First` or `Function Key First`.

#### Function Key First

This is the default option. Press any function key to perform the associated function. For multimedia action, press <kbd>Fn</kbd> + the required multimedia key.

#### Multimedia Key First

Press any multimedia key to perform the associated multimedia action. For function, press <kbd>Fn</kbd> + the required function key.

Comment: This answer only applies to a certain manufacturer's BIOS.  You should specify which manufacturer you're referring to.  It is not a universally-true concept.

Comment: @Stabledog I have tested this in DELL and used similar functionality in HP.

Answer (score 1):

On Dell machines, this is a very trivial process.

On boot, hit F2 and enter the Setup Utility. Go to `Advance > Function key behavior > Select Multimedia key`, and you should find what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

On my Samsung Notebook 9 Pro, there is a "FN Lock" key to the right of the F12 key that reverses the FN buttons. It lights up like the Capslock key when it is activated so you always know when its on.

Answer (score 0):

On an `HP Elitebook` I had to press `Fn + Fn lock` to revert to the previous state.