# Why is my Windows Surface Pro fn key stuck on?

Tags: microsoft-surface, microsoft-surface-pro

It seemed like out of nowhere my Windows Surface type pad PgUp and PgDn keys stopped working, being replaced by their F11 and F12 values instead. How do I get it back to normal?

Answer (score 4):

Per [these two](http://www.surfaceproblog.com/trick-lock-the-fn-key/) [blog posts](http://blogs.technet.com/b/toml/archive/2013/10/30/surface-pro-and-function-fn-key-lock.aspx), there is a new update which lets you default the Fn key to being pressed instead of being off. To switch between the two, hit <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Caps</kbd>.  Note that you must press and hold <kbd>Fn</kbd> first, then press <kbd>Caps</kbd> for this to work.