# Reversing Fn key - Logitech Keyboard K290

Tags: keyboard, hotkeys, function-keys, fn-key

My question is similar to this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/735062/how-to-invert-the-fn-key) but the situation here is in an external keyboard (Logitech Comfort Keyboard K290). Is there anyway I can revert the Fn key to behave as it is pressed all the time?

note : this is not a problem, this is the default of the keyboard. all `F` keys cannot be pressed without `Fn` key as the default ones are shortcuts (brightness - volume - media - ..etc)

I am wiring the keyboard to Asus K55VD - Windows 8

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For anyone else that stumbles upon this question. SetPoint now includes a checkbox that enables you to change the default setting back to using F1-F12 instead of media keys:

[image]

Comment: The problem with multi login work in Windows

Answer (score 2):

For all the people still wondering how to do this on Linux, here is the link to the solution:

https://github.com/milgner/k290-fnkeyctl

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4E5R.png)for those who came here looking for a solution, use powertoys. There is a keyboard remapping feature.
With it, you will select f1 and it will remap to fn+f1
Then it will select fn+f1 and remap to f1. With this you will reverse the order of the keys

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: (1) Please don’t post screen images unless they actually ***illustrate*** your answer.  (2) That goes double when they contain non-English text.

Answer (score -1):

Logitech keyboards can now toggle the default status of the `FN` key without any software by pressing `FN`+`ESC`.

Comment: `FN`+`ESC` does not work on my K290. 
The escape doesn't even have any alternate function blue markings.