# HP Pavilion notebook

Tags: hp-pavilion

I'm having problems getting my f5 button to be used as a refresh button. I have tried all the suggestions, and all it does is light up my keyboard, which is not what I need it to do.
I'm hoping someone has something new, otherwise I will have to return my new laptop.
Thanks

Comment: Maybe you need to press Fn key with your F5 to make it act as F5. Also [see this](http://superuser.com/q/735062/432690). Besides, how can we help you find "something new" not knowing which "all the suggestions" you have tried?

Comment: How exactly are you trying to press the keys? What are you trying to refresh?

Answer (score 0):

Read the HP START HERE/SETUP INSTRUCTIONS, it is the [first thing that comes out of the box](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zYg63HwtabQ).

It explains what the functions keys do, where the modifier key is (usually Fn) and how to use it.

If you are looking for more details, then [search for your exact product and consult its manual](http://support.hp.com/us-en/products).

If using this modifier key bothers you, then [disable the Fn + Function key combination in the BIOS](http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c02035108).