# Can I change keyboard so that it is like I am pressing Fn key all the time?

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard, fn-key

My <kbd>F1</kbd> key puts my computer into sleep mode.
This is extremely annoying because my finger could slip on the <kbd>1</kbd> key and my computer has to wake up again.

Comment: Did you look for that feature in your BIOS?  I can toggle that feature in my Lenovo BIOS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to invert the Fn key](https://superuser.com/questions/735062/how-to-invert-the-fn-key)

Answer (score 0):

Some BIOS have this feature you will have to check the BIOS of the PC

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can change these settings in your bios. Boot in your bios setting and there you will find settings with <kbd>Fn</kbd> key in the advanced option of BIOS. You can go ahead and disable it easily