# How to invert FN keys on Xiaomi notebook

Tags: arch-linux, fn-key, manjaro

Subj. The problem is that by default <kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd> on [Xiaomi Notebook Air](https://xiaomi-mi.com/notebooks/xiaomi-mi-notebook-air-133-silver/) act as a FN keys (adjusting sound, screen brightness and so on) and not as <kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd>. So every time I need <kbd>F1</kbd> I actually have to press <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> or to toggle "Fn Lock" (<kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>ESC</kbd>) before.

Some of the [existing](https://superuser.com/questions/250684/how-to-invert-function-keys-on-dell-n5010) [answers](https://superuser.com/questions/735062/how-to-invert-the-fn-key) say that there might be an option somewhere in BIOS to invert that, but I was not able to find it.

So how do I invert FN keys on Xiaomi Notebook?

P.S. I'm using Manjaro / Arch Linux, but I want a hardware / BIOS solution if possible.

Comment: If there is no option and nothing is listed in the User's Manual, then it is likely not possible to invert the Fn keys.

Answer (score 26):

I came looking for an answer, because it has been driving me crazy, but just solved it myself (on the Mi 15" pro, assume the same one air):

<kbd>Fn + Esc</kbd> inverts it, easy!

Comment: Works on ThinkPads as well.

Comment: How do you change it by default?